# Linux From Scratch 7.2: Error while making binutils-2.22 in chapter 6

Tags: compiling, lfs

I  get the following error while executing `make tooldir=/usr`

```
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:130:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:130:7: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:131:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:131:7: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'realloc' [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/bits/string2.h:1296:0,
             from /usr/include/string.h:633,
             from ../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:149:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:470:14: error: conflicting types for 'malloc'
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:130:7: note: previous declaration of 'malloc' was here
In file included from ../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:638:0:
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'byte_regex_compile':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:2439:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:2439:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:2500:17: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:2533:36: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:2640:28: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:3643:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:4150:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'byte_re_compile_fastmap':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:4835:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'abort' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:4835:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'abort' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'byte_re_match_2_internal':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:7424:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'abort' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'xregcomp':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:7978:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'xregexec':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:8053:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'xregerror':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:8081:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'abort' [enabled by default]
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c: In function 'xregfree':
../../binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c:8114:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]
make[2]: *** [regex.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/sources/binutils-build/libiberty'
make[1]: *** [all-libiberty] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/binutils-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The complete output is [here](http://pastebin.com/GkT5TAUp), and the page I was using is [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/binutils.html)

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

`/usr/include/stdlib.h` (line 470)

```
extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __wur;
```

`binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c` (line 130)

```
char *malloc ();
```

Comment: Could you give the declarations of malloc in files `/usr/include/stdlib.h` (line 470) and `binutils-2.22/libiberty/regex.c` (line 130)

Comment: What CFLAGS are you using to compile?

Comment: The default ones. I havent added anything

Comment: And I am compiling on ubuntu 10.04 64bit

Comment: you should run `configure` before `make`. I also saw you don't include `/usr/include` at line 540.

Comment: binutils 2.22 is 4 years old now, you should use a newer version (whether that's relevant to this problem or not).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that STDC_HEADERS is not defined when you are compiling the code.   See line 47 of [that version of regex.c](http://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=libiberty/regex.c;h=d65eedb16704313a58f293c0c9e00600e51a29a2;hb=0aff3d5c72d5c090be861f34f8aa543fb6590e45).   This probably happened because you didn't run `configure` or you did but something went wrong.

If you hadn't run configure, just go ahead and run it:

```
./configure
```

If you do run it, it should generate a file called `config.h` which should use `#define` to define the macro `STDC_HEADERS` to some value.   If not, it's possible that the compiler you are using is missing something it depends on (such as system header files) or is misconfigured or incorrectly installed.

As I mentioned in a comment above though, the release of binutils you're using is [over 4 years old now](http://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=0aff3d5c72d5c090be861f34f8aa543fb6590e45) and you should use a newer version I think.